# Combining the swarm (pso and particle-swarm)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

While doing a bit of editing on Python questions, I noticed [pso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pso) and [particle-swarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/particle-swarm) tags on one of them.

Considering that they both talk about the same thing (particle swarm optmization), and having read the Wiki description for both, [particle-swarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/particle-swarm) is the stronger of the two, and I feel that [pso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pso) should be made a synonym for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the acronym tags are inherently confusing but luckily for us, there was no other major [PSO abbreviation in computer science and programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSO).

There were 66 questions in [pso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pso), out of which 14 already had the [particle-swarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/particle-swarm) tag. I went through the list of 22 questions that came up when I did a search for `[pso] -"swarm" is:q -[particle-swarm]` and all of them were related to Particle Swarm.

I have now merged the tags, [particle-swarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/particle-swarm) is the master and [pso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pso) is the synonym.